# Cause of Tkinter error when displaying matplotlib graphs using PySimpleGUI

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, pysimplegui

I am currently developing a GUI in Python using PySimpleGUI and am working on plotting some graphs in frames contained by the main window. I succeeded in doing this using this example code[1](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Matplotlib.py) [and it looks fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A45BS.png) However, when I close the main window after having plotted a graph, I get the following list of errors related to Tkinter:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback\
Traceback (most recent call last):\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__\
    return self.func(*args)\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3072, in set\
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'set', first, last)\
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name\ ".!toplevel.!frame.!notebook.!frame4.!frame4.!tkscrollableframe.!scrollbar2"\
Exception in Tkinter callback\
Traceback (most recent call last):\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__\
    return self.func(*args)\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3072, in set\
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'set', first, last)\
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name\ ".!toplevel.!frame.!notebook.!frame4.!frame4.!tkscrollableframe.!scrollbar"\
Exception in Tkinter callback\
Traceback (most recent call last):\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__\
    return self.func(*args)\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3072, in set\
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'set', first, last)\
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name\ ".!toplevel.!frame.!notebook.!frame4.!frame4.!tkscrollableframe.!scrollbar2"\
Exception in Tkinter callback\
Traceback (most recent call last):\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__\
    return self.func(*args)\
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3072, in set\
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'set', first, last)\
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name\ ".!toplevel.!frame.!notebook.!frame4.!frame4.!tkscrollableframe.!scrollbar"\
```

I am new to matplotlib and haven't used Tkinter before, but would like to know the cause of these errors, if anyone knows. My code is quite big, but I can add it to the post if necessary.
I have tried commenting different parts of my code to find the culprit and when I remove the line corresponding to the following in the demo I used, the errors stopped:

```
figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
```

Have anyone experienced this problem before? I am running this on a machine running Centos and have tried running a simpler program in Windows, which closes without any problem.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Upon request I have just added the simplest Python code I could produce that reproduces this kind of error:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib as mp
from matplotlib import figure
from matplotlib.backends import backend_tkagg
import numpy as np

layout1 =   [
                [
                    sg.Frame("Frame",
                                [
                                    [
                                        sg.Column(
                                                    [
                                                        [sg.Canvas(key="-CANVAS-")] 
                                                    ],
                                                    size=(1000,1000)
                                                )
                                    ] 
                                ]
                            )
                ] 
            ]

layout2 =   [
                [sg.Column(layout1, scrollable=True)] 
            ] 

window = sg.Window("Window", layout2)
window.finalize()

x = np.array(list(range(10)))
fig = figure.Figure()
ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1))
ax.plot(x, x)

figure_canvas_tkagg = backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window["-CANVAS-"].TKCanvas)
figure_canvas_tkagg.draw()
figure_canvas_tkagg.get_tk_widget().pack()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

It appears that it might have something to do with the fact that my GUI code consists of many levels of container-objects within cointainer-objects. In my full code I have a couple of layers on top of this, but the error seemed to appear once I made the following hierarchy:

Column
Frame
Column
Canvas

It should be noted that using the debugger of Visual Studio Code I have found out that the error does not occur exactly when the window closes (when the window.close() method is called), but some time before.

EDIT 2: I just tested it and for some reason this error only occurs when I run the attached Python script on my Centos machine and not in Windows.

EDIT 3: I found out that if I close all the figures I have created before I close the window, these errors will not occur. This is not a complete fix however, since the error occur before the window.close() command of PySimpleGUI is run, so I don't know where to put the code that would close the figures in case the window is closed.

Comment: Can you please show us some minimal code that produces the error?

Comment: Just added some code

Comment: Nothing wrong after run your script. From failure message, it looks like it set the scrollbar position but scrollbar not exist, maybe caused by window already destroied or closed.

Comment: So you don't have any problems when you try running the script? That's strange. But I don't know why scrollbars should cause this problem. On the other hand I don't know how the underlying Tkinter, that PySimpleGUI builds upon, works, so it might be something in the implementation of PySimpleGUI. At least it does not affect the functionality of my GUI, as the errors don't occur until I close it, but it would be nice to get rid of them.